# Change the Identity Login's success url instead /Home/Index in .NET core

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-identity

I have developed a .NET core 2.2 project using Individual (Identity Authentication). After login is successful from **/Identity/Account/Login** application routes to **/Home/Index**

But I want that after login is successful the page should Redirect to **/Dashboard/Index** , another view in my project. How should I implement this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to scaffold in the `Login` page (if you haven't already) and change it in the code behind. However, that's just the default if no returnUrl is provided. Normally, the user will be prompted to login because they've attempted to go to some area that requires authorization, such as `/Dashboard/Index` in your scenario. If they navigate to `/Dashboard/Index` and are redirected to the login page to authenticate, then they will be  redirected back to `/Dashboard/Index` once they're logged in.

Comment: I got the solution is to use [Authorize] attribute before the Controller's method which works with ReturnURL. Thanks anyway :-)

Comment: I'd read a bit deeper into Chris P's answer. It will work with almost any page that redirects the user to log in. Why write all these attribute statements in your code when you don't actually need to?

Answer (score 1):

In `.NET Core 5` What I have done is I have scaffolded Identity and and checked overridden Login/register pages. It creates a class file where you can update your code like this.

The generated file location is : `Areas\Identity\Pages\Account\Login.cshtml.cs`

```
 public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync(string returnUrl = null)
        {
            returnUrl ??= Url.Content("~/Dashboard/Index"); // Change the default login redirect url to Dashboard/Index

            ExternalLogins = (await _signInManager.GetExternalAuthenticationSchemesAsync()).ToList();
```